# How to serve generated static HTML file with Jersey 2?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey-2.0, asciidoctor

My Maven build generates a static HTML based on Asciidoc sources.
I would like to serve this file as a welcome page of my Jersey 2 application.

Please note I do not have any servlet configuration, as `spring-boot-starter-jersey` handles this by itself.

I have struggled for some time now and I'm not sure there is an elegant to do this.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: Yes, and this relies on Spring MVC, I'm using the *Jersey* starter, my app defines its resources with Jersey 2.